# How to implement a Tab Sync feature to a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, database, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension that manages tabs, and I would like to add a Tab Sync feature to synchronize tab data across different devices for users who are signed in to their Chrome browser. I am fairely new to programming and this is my first ever project. I am working on a tab management extension and would like to implement a feature that will alow you to open all the tabs you last had open on one device and open them all on any device which has the extension open.

I did some research and saw that I should first implement some kind of user authentication and send the user data to a some kind of database to store user-related data. Is this correct and if so what websites/system should I use and how do I implement it into my code?

Comment: "I did some research" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.